# BinaryWriter and BinaryReader in C++

Tags: c++, linux

I am working in C++ in linux. I am wondering is there a BinaryReader and BinaryWriter equivalence of the C# in linux?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you want to work with binary files you can use the plain C API (fopen/fread/fwrite/fclose) or lookup C++'s libraries: iostream and fstream

Answer (score 3):

The closest you can get is with the `ofstream` and `ifstream` classes:

```
// Write an integer, a double and a string to a binary file using ofstream
std::ofstream out("out.data", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
out << 10 << ' ' << 893.322 << ' ' << "hello, world" << std::endl;
out.close();

// Read an integer, a double and a string from a binary file using ifstream:
std::ifstream in("in.data", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
int i = 0;
double d = 0.0f;
std::string s;
in >> i;
in >> d;
in >> s; // reads up to a whitespace.

// or you can read the entire file in one shot:
std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << in.rdbuf();
s = buffer.str(); // the entire file contents as an array of bytes.

in.close();
```

Comment: BinaryWriter etc write the data as binary data so if you output an int you get the bytes of the int. This converts them to a string. The ios_base:binary just tells the stream not to convert end of line characters, it doesn't do what I suspect the original poster wants.

Answer (score 2):

There are the [iostream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/iostream/) libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Check for the usage of the standard `iostream` and `fstream` classes. Using the C API is a pity but still possible.

Answer (score 1):

You have to open an fstream in binary mode and then use the read and write functions to perform binary reads and writes.

Something like this -

```
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
   std::ofstream out("out.data", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary); 

   int a = 120;
   out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&a), sizeof(int));
   out.close(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer: no.

In response to the other answers:
The standard template library provides classes to stream data, but does not provide any high-level functionality to convert data into a serialized binary format and back again.

The << and >> operators can work for classes that explicitly have code written to support them. But this doesn't come close to what the BinaryWriter and BinaryReader can do, which is to stream entire graphs of objects, taking circular references into account.In .NET, all that's required is that each of the classes have the [Serializable] attribute applied to them.

If you think about the differences between C++ and C#, you could understand why a complete  binary formatter isn't provided. Issues I can think of are

- C++ does not have the reflection capabilities of C#.
- As C++ does not have managed memory, it would be impossible to stream an object graph, taking into account circular  references.

Comment: std::(i|o)stream are the byte streams. The operators << and >> are the "toString reflection" to relate to.

Comment: @Artyom - the std::iostreams provide a way to stream serialized data. It does not help with the conversion of an object graph INTO the serialized data in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

you only need one library: `boost::serialization`

Answer (score -1):

Unlike C# where strings are sequences of two byte "words" and encoded as UTF-16. C++ strings (std::string) are bytes sequences and they are usually encoded with UTF-8 or other local encodings depending on your system.

So there is no character set conversion when you write a string to the "byte-stream" so ordinary file streams like std::fstream or in-memory streams like std::stringstreadm all derived from std::ostream and/or std::istream and are actually the byte streams you are looking for.

Comment: The C# binary formatter can format any object, not just strings.

Comment: @Andrew Shepherd - if they implement ToString() in reasonable way... Same way if `operator<<` is implemented it can format any C++ object.